# Stylize <select> with css

Tags: css, forms, drop-down-menu

How do I achieve the style like the image below?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/selectstyle.gif/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery plugins.
[for example](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/128/), 
[and more](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/)

Comment: Thanx Londeren. I was looking for the specific look as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? If you are, do a search for custom dropdown framework like this one by [Filament Group](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

If you are curious and want to do it yourself. Read on.

You cannot really style the  element to that extent, but the trick is to replace that element via JS with a trigger element (usually an `<a>`) and the list overlay (usually `<ul>` positioned absolutely and hidden at first). Then, when the trigger element is mousedown-ed, you show/hide the overlay.

Of course, you also need to handle the click event for the individual list item overlay. And it's also a good idea to take care of keyboard interaction and focus/blur states.

Hope that points you to the right direction.